# MS Access Too Few Parameters: Expected 1

Tags: ms-access

So I'm trying to take data from a table, set that piece of data to a variable, and add that variable into a new table.
This is the code to access the last name of the person I'm searching for. I'm almost 100% sure this part works.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim Lrs As DAO.Recordset
Dim LSQL As String
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set Lrs = db.OpenRecordset("Select [LastName]" & _
      "From ['Chromebook Registration Form]" & _
      "Where [InventoryNumber] = 1")
dbLastName = Lrs("LastName")
```

In debug mode, it shows that the variable "dbLastName" contains the string that I want.

However, when I run the following code (to add the information into a new table), I get a 3061 Run-time error code. Too few parameters: expected 1.
The debugger says the problem is in the last line. I assume it is a problem with "dbLastName". The timestamp thing works fine.

```
CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO TempReg " _
              & "([Timestamp], LName, FName, Grade, InventoryNumber, SerialNumber, MacAddress, PaidIn, CheckNum) VALUES " _
              & "(Now, dbLastName, 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test');"
```

Thank you!

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just embed a string variable into SQL. Instead of

```
(Now, dbLastName, 'test ...
```

You need

```
(Now(), '" & dbLastName & "', 'test' …
```

In addition you need to make sure your variable will never include the single quote character, otherwise you have to also take that into account by doubling it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm just getting started with SQL/VBA, so this is all new to me.